# Task not found in project

Tags: android, gradle

I'm having an issue relatively to gradle which I don't know how to solve it...

If I put this command on my terminal : `gradle --scan :<module A>:debugCompileClasspath`

This is what it shows me :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project '<root_project_file>'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.2).
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/3.1.2/gradle-core-3.1.2.jar
> Could not find layoutlib-api.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.1.2).
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/26.1.2/layoutlib-api-26.1.2.jar
```

How can I solve this ?

P.S: My Gradle Android plugin is `3.1.2` and gradle version : `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`

P.S.2 : Clearing the cache of gradle, now disappears those errors but i have this problem now ... `Task 'debugCompileClasspath' not found in project ':<Module_porject>'.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47216956/9025311

Comment: @Eminem now my problem is different !

Comment: what changed?..

Comment: @Eminem just cleared the cache of Gradleby doing those commands :
` rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches  ` and `./gradlew cleanBuildCache`

Comment: I think that you have a dependency problem,take a look at this question and answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/47399070/9025311

Comment: @Eminem did that too

Comment: I haven't updated my AS yet, however I encourage you to try all the answers,most recent post regarding this prb is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218614/gradle-4-0-unable-to-find-a-matching-configuration hope it helps

Comment: @Eminem I guess I have no others option. I'll try and keep informed :) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So....
It seems that jcenter() repository had some problems recently (server issues), which means that gradle was having some conflicts to build the project...
I checked the status of bintray in twitter and waited that the problem was solved, then I cleared the cache of gradle in my computer (mac os) with those commands :

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

Finally, the project was building everything correctly with no errors !
Hope it will help the next adventurers.
Cheers :)